Enabling both touch and click event on a leaflet control
I must start off by admitting that all this is super-new to me. I have created a custom control to show info about markers. The control creates an info panel that is enabled for both touch (on devices with touch capability) and click. The control has buttons to open/close/shrink the info panel. However, if I enable the touch events, the click events stop working. If I disable the touch events, the clicks work. I would like both to be enabled.
A little search shows variations of this question but they are not specific to leaflet. Any suggestions on how to solve this?
Here is my simplified code
const Slidebar = L.Control.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.on('swipeup', function(e) {
            toggleSize('full');
        });
        this.on('swipedown', function(e) {
            toggleSize('half');
        });
    },

    toggleSize: function(size) {
        … code to change size …
    },

    addTo: function(map) {
        L.DomEvent.on(
            this._container, 
            'touchstart', 
            this._startSwipe, 
            this
        );

        L.DomEvent.on(
            this._container, 
            'touchend', 
            this._endSwipe, 
            this
        );

        const that = this;
        const full = document.querySelector('#full');
        const half = document.querySelector('#half');
        full.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            that.toggleSize('full');
        });
        half.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            that.toggleSize('half');
        });

        // methods to calc swipe amount and direction
        _startSwipe: function(e) {
        },

        _endSwipe: function(e) {
            const dir = …
            const val = …
            this.fire(`swipe${dir}`, { dir, val })
        }
    }

